Bhavishya Purana Copy
I have been looking online for a copy of the Bhavishya Purana and I only found Hindi and Sanskrit copies on internet archive. These are the ones I cannot read that well. I was able to find a bengali version of it online but I am having a hard time downloading it (I need to pay to make an online account). Does anyone have a copy of the bengali Bhavishya Purana or can anyone provide a link to a website from which I can freely download one?

Why don't you search for English

@HariKumar Hello. Only the Pratisarga Parva is available in English. I want to see the whole Purana. Also, although my first language is English, I do not really like reading Hindu scriptures in English, since Sanskrit terms are not always completely relatable to English words.

@Debbie Could you please tell me the website where it is offered under a paid account? I will see if I can get that for you.

@Pankaj The original site I found the bengali copy is this one (https://www.scribd.com/document/463682907/%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%B7-%E0%A6%AF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A3-%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE-pdf)

@Pankaj However, I have found a way to get a copy for free, so no need to get one. Thanks for the offer though!
